# Pointing a domain name that is already attached to a server

Tags: domains

I have a server with a domain name. I also have a website on [Nation Builder](http://nationbuilder.com/). What I want is for my my Nation Builder site to show up when you go to my server's domain name. However, I have data I need to access on the server. Is there a way to make my servers domain show my nation builder site while still allowing me to access the information on the server?

I am trying to avoid having to change the domain name of my server. I want the domain for my Nation Builder site. So I am trying to see if I can use it for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the same URL to point to both server and your website. However, you can create subdomains and point to your server and website separately.

For example: you can have `server.domain.com` point to your server and `www.domain.com` to your website.

Comment: Ok I did not think of that. However I actually am thinking of just switching the domain names of my server and of my website. Changing all the names of the records shouldn't mess stuff up on my server right? Sorry I am very new to this.